# Move element with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't move the last div inside the `titolo` class to the right.

Inside the div with the `titolo` class there are 5 more divs.
The last div of these 5 should move to the right.
I would like to avoid using the margin for moving

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks so much!!

[JSBin demo](https://jsbin.com/giyiduz/edit?html,css,output)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.bannerSup {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px
}

.titolo {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 15px;
}

.titolo a {
  color: aliceblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.titolo>div {
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

div.titolo>div>a.contatti {
  color: red;
}

div.titolo>div:nth-child(5) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.bannerInf {
  border: 10px solid azure;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

#banner1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerSup">
  <div class="titolo">
    <div> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">PRODOTTI</a></div>
    <div> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">ABOUT US</a></div>
    <div> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">STORY</a></div>
    <div> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">CONTACTS</a></div>
    <div> <a class="contatti">CONTACTS</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="bannerInf">
    <img id="banner1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x100" alt="Immagine Banner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _I would like to avoid using the margin for moving_: why?

Comment: Align-self operates on the cross-axis. That won't help here.

Comment: Would `auto` be an hardcoded value in this context?

Comment: 1 option is to group first 4 elements and then `justtify content between` on the `.titolo`

Comment: Add another div wrapping the first four divs and set .Titolo justify-content: space-evenly. Or space-between with some margin/padding depending which result you feel looks best

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!